# Android Activity с чем то вроде Flash View

Tags: android, flash-player

Суoествует ли способ воспроизвести swf файл напрямую на Android? Каким образом можно реализовать приложение с присутсвием Flash? Подскажие сущестующие для этого компоненты.

Суть в следующем. Есть приложение со списком, например, видеороликов в формате swf. по выбору ролика, он должен открыться на весь экран.

Использование формата swf принципиально по некоторым соображениям, которыми, к сожалению, я не могу поделиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

инструкция как писать для андроида на  Adobe AIR

http://flashsimulations.com/2010/10/19/developing-android-applications-with-adobe-air/